# WP7 C# How close one application from another?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want close external applications in suspend mode from my own application.

For example :

I run WebBrowserTask from my app

```
        var wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
        wbt.URL = "www.site.com";
        wbt.Show();
```

and after i want kill (close, finish) this task from my app.

Please any ideas how this can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close your or any other application. You must leave handling Application life cycle to the OS.

In your case when you create a `WebBrowserTask` your application becomes suspended and wont get any CPU time so none of your code will run until it becomes activated again.

Comment: +1 - but actually, your application can afterwards get some CPU before it gets suspended, and also you can register background tasks that will still spin, but anyways, there is really no way to close an app due to the design of this layer of OS.

Comment: ie there is no way to close unnecessary programs automatically? It may be possible to create a process that will keep track of all running programs and close some of them?

Comment: @user2357123 No you cannot close other or even your own app, the OS will take care of managing resources. If you had the capability to close some other app it'd become confusing for the user because they expect having that app in the background.

Answer (score 1):

SoroushMirzaei already said everything, but I'll add a bit of doubt: Why are you trying to open-and-close this webbrowser and site? If you want to show a nag screen for X seconds or do some website-logon etc, use fullscreen WebBrowser control, where you will have 100% control over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close another application from your code. In your case, you could use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control so that the user remains within your app itself. This may require more work, depending on how much of the `WebBrowserTask` functionality you need but it gives you full control on when and where the web pages are displayed.

Comment: ie there is no way to close unnecessary programs automatically? It may be possible to create a process that will keep track of all running programs and close some of them?

Comment: @user2357123 - No, the design behind it is that the OS will handle the closing of all applications. So, for example, you can't create a task killer application using the current SDK.